# NodeJS and Express - How to store data in Array and not render in a web browser DOM?

Tags: node.js, express, dom

I have a route in node - express and it is working properly - getting data from a database.

```
app.get('/getdata/:key', function(req, res){

  console.log("Search key(s):", req.originalUrl.split("/")[2]);

  keys =  req.originalUrl.split("/")[2]
  Keys = keys

  arr = keys.split(",");

  client.mget(arr, function (err, Values) {
    res.send({ Keys, Values});
  });

});
```

But I do not want to display all data (records) into the browser screen (DOM) - just want to get it as array and parse it later with some JavaScript in a browser.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Return JSON from the server.  Request the data via an AJAX request in a web page, get the JSON, parse it into the Javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending all data at once, so the client will not do another request. You must filter the data at the client's side.

As it is probably an array of objects, you could use `.filter` function.
Here you have some info about how to do the filtering: [w3chools - JavaScript Array filter() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As @jfreind00 recommended - return it as JSON.

Perform a `GET` request with JS in your Front-end:

```
http.get('/getdata/${key}', (err, res) => {
// do something with your data here
}
```

Depending on your used frameworks this code could differ.